# NiFi: QueryRecord using ExecuteScript

Tags: apache-nifi

I consume data from a kafka topic (`nested json`) which has to be filtered based on a field value.
So I used the `ExecuteScript processor` to filter out records and transform some fields.
For filtering I used `findAll` function without using QueryRecord and it worked.

My question here is does this approach solve the same purpose as QueryRecord processor for filtering
because I'm NOT sure how to use query record when there are nested json objects from the incoming flowfiles.

I tried queryrecord but it threw an error:

```
SELECT * FROM FLOWFILE WHERE RPATH(order, '/orderDetail/orderId') = '1126'

Error:
No match found for function signature RPATH(<JavaType(...Record)>,<CHARACTER>)
org.apache.calcite.runtime.CalciteContextException

Sample Data:

{  
   "retail":{  
      "retailId":"6133",
      "retailName":"Maveric"
   },
   "order":{  
      "orderDetail":{  
         "orderId":"1126",
         "orderName":"NNDRFG"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RPATH_STRING is not the correct syntax, it is just RPATH.

See the additional details documentation for QueryRecord:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryRecord/additionalDetails.html

It has an example of JSON with nested fields.

Comment: Bryan,thanks, still facing the same issue. I have updated the question with the error message and the data from ConsumeKafkaRecord processor.

Comment: What version of NiFi are you using?

Comment: Its Apache NiFi 1.8.0

Comment: RPATH is added in 1.9.0 :) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5903

Comment: If you have a single json per flow file, you can use EvaluateJsonPath to extract whatever the path is into an attribute, then RouteOnAttribute to route the value you are interested in

Comment: No, its a list of json elements. I didn't want to splitJson as the data looks huge. Do you think thats the only way to go :(

Comment: Ok probably just stick with ExecuteScript then until you upgrade and can use QueryRecord